# Is using an IN over a huge data set a good idea?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

Let's say I have a query of the form:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d 
FROM table1 
WHERE a IN (
  SELECT x 
  FROM table2 
  WHERE some_condition);
```

Now the query for the `IN` can return a huge number of records.
Assuming that `a` is the primary key, so an index is used is this the best way to write such a query?

Or it is more optimal to loop over each of the records returned by the subquery?

For me it is clear that when I do a `where a = X` it is clear that I just do an index (tree) traversal.
But I am not sure how an `IN` (especially over a huge data set) would traverse/utilize an index.

Comment: Is that database-independent question, or you have a specific RDBMS  in mind?

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric:I have tagged it `MySQL` since this is what I use. So it is not a generic question.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL optimizer isn't really ready (jet) to handle this correctly you should rewrite this kind of query to a iNNER JOIN and index correctly this will be the fasted method assuming t1.a and t2.x are unique

something like this.

```
SELECT 
a
, b
, c
, d
FROM 
  table1 as t1
INNER JOIN
  table2 as t2
ON t1.a = t2.x
WHERE 
 t1.some_condition ....
```

And make sure that t1.a and t2.x have PRIMARY or UNIQUE indexes

Comment: Your query will not give the same results as OP's (it will return the same only if `table2.x` is unique; otherwise you get duplicates...).

Answer (score 0):

Having 1 query instead of loop will be definitely more efficient (and by nature consistent , to get consistent results with loop in general you will have to use `serializable` transaction ). One can argue in favour of `EXISTS` vs `IN`; as far as I remember mysql generates (or at least it was true for up to 5.1)...

Efficiency of utilizing index on `a` depends on number and order subquery result (assuming optimizer choses to grab results from subquery first and then compare it with `a`). In my understanding, the fastest option is to perform merge join which requires both resultsets sorted by the same key; however it may not be possible due to different sort order. Then I guess it's optimizer decision whether to sort or to use loop join. You can rely on its choice or try using hints and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: 1)My query is just a `SELECT`.What does `serializable` transaction have to do with it? 2)I don't really follow you in the second paragraph (perhaps I lack the background). But I guess that if `a=2` we have just one traversal. If `a IN (3,4,5,6,7,8....1000)` what kind of traversal do we have?

Comment: 1. When you have just one query it's guaranteed that you will get consistent data - say it's possible that someone inserts/updates/deletes record from either of tables involved (`table1` or `table2`) during execution of your select. It's different when you use loop. Say you execute subquery first, then iterate through resultset, pass parameters to another query in the loop and execute it. Data in each of `table1`/`table2` may be different from what you had at the beginning of execution. It may or may not be an issue (say, you know nothing changes, or updates are prohibited)...

Comment: 2. `a=2 ` should do index seek (or clustered index seek in case of PK for INNODb tables). `a IN (3,4,....1000)` should be `[clustered]index range scan` (or full table scan if you have very small table).  But it's different from what you would get in if you put `WHERE a IN (SELECT ....)` . Queries are not executed in the order we write them in SQL. We can control physical execution (at least order) to some extent with hints, but it's up to optimizer which table to access first.

Comment: `Queries are not executed in the order we write them in SQL`, yes but in this case the inner select must be executed *before* the outer can be executed.

Comment: In your second comment I get an impression that you imply that an index can not be used directly in this case due to usage of a query in the `IN()`

Comment: 1. Agreed, in this particular case subquery should be executed first. 2. Not really, I meant index will be used, but it may be very fast if result of subquery is sorted the same way as index of `a`  or not so fast otherwise. Also, I didn't work for quite a while with MyISAM engine, all my comments/answers are with assumption you're using INNODb.

Comment: @Cratylus : After giving more thoughts, I realized that even in this case "subquery must be executed before the outer" doesn't have to be always true. If `table1` is very small, it can be cheaper to read it completely regardless of subquery result...

Comment: If I do the second `SELECT` individually and gather all the results and then loop over each result using a prepared query why isn't it faster? The query will be cached and since I will look for only one element I will not be searching in ranges.

Comment: @Cratylus : In this case each individual query will be faster than original, but all together will be slower. As a rule of thumb, set-based logic (1 query) outperform cursor-based logic (multiple queries)