# Why is IN() considered O(logN) operation?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

Researching further for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166265/is-using-an-in-over-a-huge-data-set-a-good-idea/18166385?noredirect=1#comment26623577_18166385) I found the following in the book High Peformance MySQL(p.219):

> ... MySQL sorts the values in the IN list and uses a fast binary
>   search to see whether a value is in the list.

It considers this approach optimal, measuring as `O(logN)` in the size of the list and that it is a very good approach (instead e.g. of converting to a series of `OR` statements).
But it seems to neglect that the sorting of the list is `O(NlogN)` so the result is worse than doing a series of `OR` which is `O(N)`.
What am I misunderstanding here?
To be clear this targets that case that the list is a huge result set coming from another `SELECT`

Answer (score 5):

First, this statement is just not true for `in` with a subquery.  For that, either the subquery is run for every row in the data (pre 5.6 MySQL) or a join optimization is used.

Second, there are two things going on when calculating the order of the `in` with a list.  Implicit in both your statements is "for each row being process".  So, if R rows are being processed, then the actual statement is `O(R * logN)` versus `O(R*N)` where `N` is the size of the list.

The creation of the sorted list takes place at compile time an happens once.  So, the order statement is `O((R * logN) + N * logN))`.  I believe the assumption is that `R` >> `N`, so it dominates the expression.  In other words, because the sorting happens once and the algorithm is looked at for each row, the compile effort drops out.

Comment: +1 FWIW, `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` runs the subquery for each distinct value in the outer query, which is distinct from `UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY` which does run the subquery for every row in the outer query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff:What if `N` is almost as large as `R`.Would it make sense to use `IN`? Or is there a better way for this?

Comment: @Cratylus . . . If the values in the list have no duplicates and are coming from a subquery, you are always safer using `join` for the filtering rather than `in`.  If the values are constant, put them in a temporary table, build an index and use `join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff:What about doing the subquery *first* grabbing **all** the result set and build a string with the result set passing it as parameter to the `IN`?

Comment: @Cratylus . . . That is not a single query solution, but it is fine.  I would prefer to put them in a separate (temporary) table with an index, but the `in` with a constant list should have similar performance.